# Finding out all the types that conform to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on a huge Swift codebase, and I'd like to better understand a certain module within the project.

There are quite a few protocols that power the module. For example:

```
protocol Classroom { ... }
protocol ArtRoom: Classroom { ... }
protocol BandRoom: Classroom { ... }
```

Knowing where the concrete types exist is really important to get a better picture of how the module interacts with the rest of the different modules in the codebase.

However, it's difficult to find all the types that conform to each protocol. For example, doing a project wide search on `Classroom` returns 3700+ results.

Is there a way in Xcode to determine the type hierarchy?

Comment: Why did you reopen the same question twice? If the previous deduplication wasn't useful, you should comment on that question instead. In any case, can't you just search for `: Classroom`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The official recommendation from SO is: "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one."

Unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't cover all cases. Ex: `: Equatable, Classroom`

Comment: All the cases I can think of can be matched by `: Classroom`, `& Classroom`, `, Classroom`

Comment: Honestly that's a bad suggestion on SO's part. it's better to jsut comment as to why the duplicate doesn't satisfy your question, and people will vote to reopen the question